# Redirection not happening while using angular routing

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I created sample angular app and want to get directed to another page using browser url `http://localhost:1800/demo`.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sample Angular app</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the home page (app.component.ts) having code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<div class="sample-class">Sample text to test this sample angular app</div>`,
    styles: [] }) export class AppComponent {
    title = "Sample title"; };
```

Following is app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DemoComponent } from './demo/demo.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    //{ path: '', redirectTo: '/login' }
    { path: 'demo', component: DemoComponent }
]

@NgModule ({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]
})

export class AppRoutingModule{};
```

I defined demo.component.ts as

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
    selector: 'demo',
    template: `<div>Demo page</div>`,
    styles: []
})

export class DemoComponent {};
```

and its corresponding module as

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { DemoComponent } from './demo.component';

@NgModule ({
    declarations: [DemoComponent],
    exports: [DemoComponent],
    bootstrap: [DemoComponent]
})

export class DemoModule {};
```

app.component.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
        Welcome to {{title}}!
    </h1>
    <img width="300" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
    </li>
</ul>
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

When try to get `http://localhost:1800/demo`, its the same home page which is shown and no redirection happens. There is no error shown as well. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: You are missing `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your main component.html.

Comment: I added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in index.html. Still routing is not happening

Comment: No, what. you miss-understood me. Index.html contains the app root. Usually the tag is <app-root></app-root> and it's fine. By default it load the app.component so add the router outlet in the app.component.html

Comment: I added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in app.component.html as I have shown in the above code. Still the issue is there.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake that I added `router-outlet` in wrong folder. Thanks a lot for your help.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export RouterModule in your AppRoutingModule.

```
exports: [RouterModule]
```

Without exporting Angular was not able to find out your routing configuration.